# Using sed to match a pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to match a pattern thats starting with a '(' followed by four numbers, followed by a name and then ends with a ')'.

Example:
head -n5 datasets/q11data.txt, gives me this :

```
$$chi101110WHITE3.14153(0964Harry)
fooBLACK'(9835Phil)May2.8
(7613Harry)NILLfubar"'Nov
3.14153(3536Edna)'Purple$'
Thu(6586Tom)SatThu NILL
```

now we spot (0964Harry), (9835Phil) etc..

How do I extract those with sed ? Ive tried this: `cat datasets/q11data.txt | sed -ne '/(\*[0-9\]*[A-Z][a-z])/p'`.

No output from the sed command above..
And I must use sed for this.

Comment: The part *"followed by a name"* is missing from your regex. That's why it doesn't match.

Comment: I have the '*' after the numbers, does it still matter ?

Comment: `*` isn't a wildcard like you seem to be assuming. It's a modifier - it says 'zero-or-more occurrences of "0-9"`

Comment: Note that the quantifier (*) must follow, nor precede the pattern it quantifies.

Comment: @123 Only one what per line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sed will keep all text contained between open and closed brackets.

```
sed 's/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*/\1/g' file
```

#### Input

```
chi101110WHITE3.14153(0964Harry)
fooBLACK'(9835Phil)May2.8
(7613Harry)NILLfubar"'Nov
3.14153(3536Edna)'Purple$'
Thu(6586Tom)SatThu NILL
(1Phil)(2Phil)(3Phil)(4Phil)dfsdf(5Phil)
```

#### Output

```
(0964Harry)
(9835Phil)
(7613Harry)
(3536Edna)
(6586Tom)
(1Phil)(2Phil)(3Phil)(4Phil)(5Phil)
```

Answer (score 0):

if awk is acceptable,

```
awk -F'[()]' '$2 ~ /[0-9]+[A-Za-Z]+/{print $2}'
```

It treats ( and ) as field separators, hence content between those two is second filed.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't use `sed` but rather `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print join ( "\n", m/\((\w+)\)/g ),"\n"';
```

This:

- iterates line by line
- applies the regular expression match: `m/\((\w+)\)/g` which matches 'alphanumerics within brackets'
- Prints it, delimited by linefeed.

This gives:

```
0964Harry
9835Phil
7613Harry
3536Edna
6586Tom
```

The reason your pattern doesn't work though, is you seem to be misunderstanding what `*` is for.

It's not a wildcard like in `ls`, it's a modifier - it applies to the previous expression, and says 'zero or more times'.

So `[0-9]*` means zero or more instances of 0-9, so you can't match any text with it.

Comment: Why? `perl` will be anywhere `sed` is.

Comment: That's because you have two _seperate_ character classes. You should be using `[A-Za-z]`. Or perhaps just `[A-Z]` with the `i` modifier to make your regex case insenitive. Or just `\w` as I do above.

Comment: Note that `\w` is only available on some versions of sed, e.g. GNU sed. A good alternative might be to use `[^)]` to match anything other than a closing bracket.

Comment: But is supported by `perl` which is very nearly as ubiquitous as `sed` - even the "non-gnu" variants.